# Jest / Enzyme html function is not multiline and indented

Tags: jestjs, enzyme

I'm snapshot testing the HTML from a React component:

```
describe('something', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(
        <MockProvider>
            <MyCompoent />
        </MockProvider>,
    );

    test('matches the snapshot', () => {
        expect(wrapper.html()).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
});
```

This works however the snapshot is minified:

```
exports[`MyCompoent something`] = `"<section class=\\"wrapper\\"><a class=\\"backLink\\" href=\\"#gift-type\\"><i class=\\"icon ArrowLeft backLinkIcon\\"><svg xmlns=\\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\\" viewBox=\\"0 0 64 64\\"><path fill=\\"currentColor\\" fill-rule=\\"nonzero\\" d=\\"M19.053 30.01h32.12v3h-32.38l13.28 13.28-2.121 2.121L13 31.458 30.004 16l2.018 2.22z\\"></path></svg></i>Back</a><div cla....
```

How can I have the HTML nicely multiline and indented? The same thing happens when I `console.log(wrapper.html())`

In my jest-config.js I already have this:

```
module.exports = {
  snapshotSerializers: ['enzyme-to-json/serializer'],
};
```

If I don't use the render method (eg `expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();`) then the multiline and indentation works fine.